# Javascript "bump" recognition (mobile devices)

Tags: javascript, mobile, accelerometer

I need a simple solution to recognize a "bump" in a mobile web app. It's currently something like:

```
waitForBump = function () {
    if (window.DeviceMotionEvent != undefined) {
        window.addEventListener("devicemotion", accelerometerUpdate, true);
    }
}

accelerometerUpdate = function(e) {
    var aX = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x * 1;
    var aY = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y * 1;
    var aZ = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.z * 1;

    if ((aX * aY * aZ) >= 1000) { // here is the point!
        bump();
    }
}

bump = function() {
    window.removeEventListener("devicemotion", accelerometerUpdate, true);

    // do something...
}
```

Any help or tips for searching the right algorithms appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Got something better by using reference values to compare acceleration:

```
waitForBump = function () {
    if (window.DeviceMotionEvent != undefined) {
        window.addEventListener("devicemotion", accelerometerUpdate, true);
    }
}

var kFilteringFactor = 0.1;

var accX = null;
var accY = null;
var accZ = null;

accelerometerUpdate = function(e) {
    var prevAccX = accX;
    var prevAccY = accY;
    var prevAccZ = accZ;

    var aX = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x * 1;
    var aY = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y * 1;
    var aZ = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.z * 1;

    accX = aX - ((aX * kFilteringFactor) + (accX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)));
    accY = aY - ((aY * kFilteringFactor) + (accY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)));
    accZ = aZ - ((aZ * kFilteringFactor) + (accZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor)));

    if (prevAccX == null || prevAccY == null || prevAccZ == null) return;

    var deltaX = Math.abs((accX - prevAccX)) * kFilteringFactor;
    var deltaY = Math.abs((accY - prevAccY)) * kFilteringFactor;
    var deltaZ = Math.abs((accZ - prevAccZ)) * kFilteringFactor;

    if (deltaX > 2 || deltaY > 2 || deltaZ > 2) bump();
}

bump = function() {
    window.removeEventListener("devicemotion", accelerometerUpdate, true);

    accX = null;
    accY = null;
    accZ = null;

    // do something
}
```

For mine it's enough to compare the deltas being more than 2. Set this value to your appropriate threshold value and you're ready to go!